# Energy/momentum values and volume

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

In one of our lectures involving particles in a box, the following was said:

If the volume is big enough then momentum and energy values become continuous?
Why is that?

A mathematical and intuitive explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of lecture? Did you talk about quantum wells?

Comment: in this case it was about a quantum gas in a box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy levels of a simple 1D square well are
$$
E_n = \frac{h^2}{8mL^2} n^2 = E_0 n^2 
$$
as you can see $E_0$ will decrease for very large System and as such the difference between the energy levels $E_{n+1} - E_{n} = E_0$ will tend to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in quantum mechanics, but the answer is distance between energy levels (see equations for energy states here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_well and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box). The dimensions are in the denominator of the energy levels, so they are getting closer to each other (and finally becoming a continuum) when the box increases.